# how to remove a referenced component in VB6.0 Project

Tags: vb6

Currently doing a VB 6.0 project,after registering few ocx files added the same in the projects  initially  and removed it later and done the above steps from a different location with the same ocx files.Now i am having two  controls with same name present in the component dialog, want remove the unwanted reference how to do it.please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the components appear after adding a reference throught Project->References. You can surely google wich dll is associated with which ocx.

Comment: will you explain it a bit more,after registering dlls and ocx i right click the tool box Components-->Selected few components and give ok.i am pretty new to vb6.0 so please explain a bit more

Comment: @karthik You need to click on the Project menu in the menu bar. There you will find both a "Reference" and a "Components" menu-item. You need to remove a reference from the "Reference" menu-item, but which one I do not know. To find this out google the ocx, you will surely find which dlll contains it.

Comment: thank you very much solved my problem,not only the problem it gives me a clear understanding of how things work.thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue and after a few hours of digging in, I found out a solution. You need to go to Regedit and find by name your dll. Visual Basic 6.0 IDE registers it in the registry so it's not possible to remove it from IDE UI. After removing key in Regedit and restarting IDE, unwanted reference disappeared.